# How to resize /dev/sda2 when it is md0 sw raid 1

Tags: filesystems, raid, resize2fs

I just added bigger `4TB`from `2TB` ssd to the `md0` raid but the size is still the same. I tryed to resize .partition but it says it is busy. Parted is still resizing it on old size.

array:

```
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb2[3] sda2[2]
      1875210240 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 3/14 pages [12KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks

```
resize2fs /dev/sda2 
resize2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda2
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p                                                                
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 3750727680 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Fix/Ignore? Fix                                                           
Model: ATA KINGSTON SEDC450 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 3841GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  32.5MB  31.5MB                     bios_grub
 2      32.5MB  1920GB  1920GB                     raid

resize      resizepart  
(parted) resizepart 2
End?  [1920GB]? 35000GB                                                   
Error: The location 35000GB is outside of the device /dev/sda.
```

fdisk output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3.5 TiB, 3840755982336 bytes, 7501476528 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SEDC450
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 36C330A7-33FB-423A-981B-2DC29CCE3822

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048      63487      61440   30M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2  63488 3750748159 3750684672  1.8T Linux RAID

Disk /dev/sdb: 3.5 TiB, 3840755982336 bytes, 7501476528 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SEDC450
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 36C330A7-33FB-423A-981B-2DC29CCE3822

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048      63487      61440   30M BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2  63488 3750748159 3750684672  1.8T Linux RAID
```

Comment: is **35000GB** a typo ? that's 35 To, did you meant 3840GB ?

Comment: dang...you are right. Do I need to resize md0 too? It was actually typo which I missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue, I put wrong size there I did not realized that size of 3.5TB is actually 3840GB no 3500GB.

Fixed the issue thanks to comment of @archemar.